# Dating site review - Am I allowed to write site description with screenshot for each reviewed site?

Tags: legal, website-review

I want to publish a review of 100 dating websites. I didn't contact all site managers, some of them didn't reply. Am I allowed to publish description for each dating site and publish also a screenshot of their site? I hope anybody have any clue if this is legally allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some text and display an image about a website even if the manager didn't reply. However, if the manager of a website ask you to remove the review or something else, do it.

Comment: Write your "own" summary for each. Be neutral and mostly a re-wordsmith of the related site(s). Do not defame them. If you are "rating" them - garner said ratings from your users and ask for a qualification ("how long were you a member?..." etc) - add some legalese about "the opinions expressed are not those of www.<blahblahblah>.com ...... be prepared for lots of email full of incorrect legal standing

Answer (score 1):

A few examples of what you are allowed to write about companies and legally. As much as they may not like it, as much as they ask their lawyers to write you letters, you're well within your right to write about a company and review them

http://www.boycottgillette.com/

http://www.paypalsucks.com/

https://www.eff.org/issues/bloggers/legal